# Getting Unhandled event loop exception, No more handles at eclipse

Tags: eclipse, swt, ubuntu-16.04

I am using ubuntu 16, trying to import the existing maven project into eclipse.

When I am clicking on browse, I am getting "Unhandled event loop exception
No more handles".

I tried many ways (mentioned here https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=545425) to resolve this issue but unable to resolve it.

Requesting to help me to resolve this issue.

[image]

Comment: Looks more like [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=568815) which is closed saying you need at least GTK 3.20

Comment: Correspondingly, 4.17 was intended for [Ubuntu 20](https://www.eclipse.org/projects/project-plan.php?planurl=https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/development/plans/eclipse_project_plan_4_17.xml#target_environments), not 16 (which ends its general maintenance updates in a few weeks).